unity Line rendering not working in the game with canvas
hello i need help with this im trying to create a level in my game that uses line rendering to draw a arrow from a user to another and im having a problem with making it i watched all youtube videos availble for this topic but nothing worked the idea of the level is like this i want to create a canvas this canvas has multiple words and i click on a world and drag a line from it to another world this picture is a example of my idea :

like this picture the idea looks simple but the line is not showed and nothing from youtube is herlping if someone could guide me how to do it it would be really helpful
i tried all youtube videos nothing worked i need someone to give me a help with this level

Line renderer does not work with canvas.  Look for a 2d line renderer.  You probably could make it work, but it would be more trouble than its worth imo.

There is not picture in your question .. but if you work in a canvas why not simply have a UI based solution rather then Line renderer? All you need is a simple Image and adjust it's position, scale in one direction and rotation...

The unity line renderer is meant to work in 3d space.  For a canvas element line, you need a ui element.
UI Element
Lets first create an image to use for the line.  The important parameter to change on the image is the pivot.  Set the pivot x to 0, so that the image will extend from the side.  Dont worry about the size of the image, that will be set from the script.

Line Behaviour
Next lets create the script that will control the lines behaviour.  The line will need a start point and target point.  We'll also expose a variable for the thickness.  Color can be changed on the image directly at runtime, or through the script using SetColor.
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class SimpleLineUI : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Image lineImage;
    [SerializeField] private float thickness = 5;
    [SerializeField] private Color color = Color.black;

    public float Length => length;

    private Vector2 startPoint;
    private Vector2 targetPoint;
    private float length;

    private void Awake()
    {
        lineImage.color = color;

        ResetLine();
    }

    public void SetStartPoint(Vector2 position, bool update = true)
    {
        startPoint = position;

        if (update)
            UpdateLine();
    }
    public void SetTargetPoint(Vector2 position, bool update = true)
    {
        targetPoint = position;

        if (update)
            UpdateLine();
    }
    public void SetThickness(float thickness)
    {
        if (this.thickness != thickness)
        {
            this.thickness = thickness;
            lineImage.rectTransform.sizeDelta = new Vector2(length, thickness);
        }
    }
    public void SetColor(Color color)
    {
        if (this.color != color)
        {
            this.color = color;
            lineImage.color = color;
        }
    }
    public void ResetLine()
    {
        length = 0;
        SetStartPoint(Vector2.zero, false);
        SetTargetPoint(Vector2.zero, false);
        lineImage.rectTransform.sizeDelta = Vector2.zero;
    }

    private void UpdateLine()
    {
        var direction = targetPoint - startPoint;
        var rotationAngle = Mathf.Atan2(direction.y, direction.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;

        length = direction.magnitude;

        lineImage.rectTransform.anchoredPosition = startPoint;

        lineImage.rectTransform.sizeDelta = new Vector2(length, thickness);

        lineImage.rectTransform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, rotationAngle);
    }
}

Configuration
Add this component to the line image.
Assign the Image component, set the thickness of the line, and set the color.

How To Use
To start the line, set the start point using SetStartPoint.  Pass in false if the target point has not been set to avoid erratic behaviour.  Set the target point using SetTargetPoint to complete the line.
Testing
Here is the component I used to test the line.  Assign the line image and your canvas.

What this component does:
When you do your first mouse left click, the start point will be set.  Once that point is set, the script will set the target point on each update to the mouses position.  Right clicking the mouse after the start point is set will reset the line.
using UnityEngine;

public class SimpleLineUITest : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private SimpleLineUI simpleLineUI;
    [SerializeField] private Canvas canvas;

    private bool startPointSet;

    private void Update()
    {
        if (startPointSet)
        {
            simpleLineUI.SetTargetPoint(GetCanvasMousePosition());

            if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
            {
                startPointSet = false;
                simpleLineUI.ResetLine();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
            {
                simpleLineUI.SetStartPoint(GetCanvasMousePosition(), false);
                startPointSet = true;
            }
        }
    }

    private Vector2 GetCanvasMousePosition()
    {
        RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle(canvas.GetComponent<RectTransform>(), Input.mousePosition, null, out var position);
        return position;
    }
}

Final Thoughts
All of the pieces are there in order to make this work with multiple points, making it similar to line renderer.  The big difference would be that each line segment would have a single thickness.

Thank you but can u please tell met how is this applicable to my level in the photo

When you click on the first checkbox, you set the start point, and when you click on the other checkbox, you either set the target point or reset the line.
